# Execution of ERC721 Token

Tags: solidity, private-blockchain, nodejs, erc-721

I have a Node-js application where cards are generated with unique number (ID11234). So I am planning to map a token for each card. In order to get uniqueness, I went through some of the documents, at-last planned to use ERC721 token for my application.

I understood the basic functionalities used in this token, but I didn't see the execution flow of token in any documents.

1. How should I execute ERC721 token solidity files (ERC721.sol,
   ERC721BasicToken.sol, ERC721Token.sol, ERC721Basic.sol)?
2. How can I map generated tokens with each card?

Referral Links  :
https://medium.com/blockchannel/walking-through-the-erc721-full-implementation-72ad72735f3c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the reference implementation noted from the standard:

https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721/blob/master/src/contracts/tokens/nf-token.sol

It is simply the ERC721 interface and it does not include the advanced optional functionality. You can worry about that stuff later.